Redirect every URL path with a /forum/ prefix using .htaccess
I'm trying to redirect a number of URLs in my forums, using .htaccess, in the following way:
https://www.example.com/forums/10-firewall-filtering-idsips-a-security/3080-firewall-question.html
to
https://www.example.com/forum/10-firewall-filtering-idsips-a-security/3080-firewall-question.html
The only difference between the two is that the new URL does not contain the "s" at the end of word "forum". The rest of the URL, after the https://www.example.com/forum/ remains the same.

How are you redirection this?  Please provide some details on your host server/OS and your example redirection code.

"the new URL does contain the "s" at the end of word "forum"" - do you mean "does not contain"? (Or are your URLs the other way round?) What have you tried? What is the problem? Is either /forums or /forum a physical filesystem directory?

Hi Rohit, thanks for your comments. I've made the necessary corrections and added more information.   I'm using .htaccess for the redirection.  Many thanks!

Do you currently have anything in your .htaccess file(s)?

Hi Mr.White. Yes, I currently have a number of other redirects, but they won't be affected by the code that will be produced for this request.

It would be helpful to see your existing .htaccess file, as this could determine how this redirect should be implemented. If you literally just have a bunch of “redirects” (which would imply you are simply serving static files) or whether you have a front-controller pattern and using mod_rewrite? (Which builds on my question above about whether /forums or /forum are physical filesystem directories?)

To redirect all URL inside a given folder to another folder with .htaccess, try the following RewriteRule:
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^forums/(.*) /forum/$1 [R=301,L]

This RewriteRule will match any path under /forums/ and will 301 redirect it to the same path, but under /forum/.
For example:
https://www.example.com/forums/10-firewall-filtering-idsips-a-security/3080-firewall-question.html ➡️301➡️ https://www.example.com/forum/10-firewall-filtering-idsips-a-security/3080-firewall-question.html
but also:
https://www.example.com/forums/foobar ➡️301➡️ https://www.example.com/forum/foobar
